# Use combobox in savepath

Tags: vb.net, save, ethernet

first of all: Sorry for the not so clear title. I didn't know a better way to descripe my question.

I'm building a application that has to save user-specified data to a sdcard on a plc. 
I already found out how to connect to that plc but am still working on the saving part. 
For the testing i just used:

```
  ds.WriteXml("C:\" & DateTimePicker1.Text & ".xml")
```

I think it's possible to change it to \192.168.2.16\SDcard\filename but that's not very flexible. 
What i would like to have is the ability to take the value from a combobox and use that as the ip adress. 
What is the best way to do this? as i don't think it's a simpe thing like making the savepad 
(\" & comboIP.selectedvalue & "\Sdcard\" & DateTimePicker1.Text & ".xml") Unfortunately, the SD card is still on it's way so i can't test it yet..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ds.WriteXml("C:\" & comboIP.Text  & "\SDCard\" & DateTimePicker1.Text & ".xml")
```

That works just fine.

You don't really need the SDCard in hand to test this out.

You can simply create temporary variables before the WriteXML function call, set a breakpoint on them, and ensure that they are the correct values beforehand.

e.g.:

```
Dim sSelectedIP As String = comboIP.Text
Dim sDateTimePicker As String = DateTimePicker1.Text
Dim sCompleteDirectory As String = "C:\" & sSelectedIP  & "\SDCard"

If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(sCompleteDirectory) = False Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(sCompleteDirectory)
End If

ds.WriteXml(sCompleteDirectory & "\" & sDateTimePicker & ".xml")
```

Comment: Yeah, i wouldn't have figured that one out. I tried some ways, without the C:\ in front of it. I thought that it would just create a new folder in C:\ then. But thanks, i will try this.

Comment: Did some testing and it does looks like it tries to save in C:.. i get a directorynotfound error.

Comment: Updated. You have to check for and create the directory.

Comment: Thanks, it stores on the C partition now in a folder with the ip adres. So it does partially work. I assume that when i get to saving it to the PLC, i can just remove the "C:\" from sCompleteDirectory?

Comment: Yes, you can change that to whatever drive you'd like.

Comment: Good, so then it will save on (for example) & sSelectedIP  & "\SDCard  Great! Thanks! Will test it as soon as the SD card arrives.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Hey, Well, nothing yet. Changed the code but it doesn't work. Trying to save files onto a unitronics PLC and apparently that's not possible in this way unfortunatly. Maybe some of you know how to?

Comment: I've never worked with one. Does it have a drive letter?

Comment: If not, I would try browsing their forums: http://www.unitronics.com/support/webinars/sd-card

Comment: Hey, nope, no drive letter unfortunatly. Would make it much easier ;)